# Spark Streaming shuffle data size on disk keeps increasing

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a basic spark streaming app that reads in logs from kafka and does a join with a batch RDD and saves the result to cassandra

```
val users = sparkStmContext.cassandraTable[User](usersKeyspace, usersTable)

KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
    sparkStmContext, Map(("zookeeper.connect", zkConnectionString), ("group.id", groupId)), Map(TOPIC -> 1), StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
    .transform(rdd => StreamTransformations.joinLogsWithUsers(rdd, users)) // simple join with users batch RDD and stream RDD
    .saveToCassandra("users", "user_logs")
```

when running this though I notice that some of the shuffle data in "spark.local.dir" is not being removed and the directory size keeps growing until I run out of disk space.
Spark is supposed to take care of deleting this data ([see last comment from TD](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5836)).

I set the "spark.cleaner.ttl" but this had no effect.

Is this happening because I create the users RDD outside of the stream and using lazy loading to reload it every streaming window (as the user table can be updated by another process) and hence then it never goes out of scope?

Is there a better pattern to use for this use case as any [docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/8_streaming.md) I have seen have taken the same approach as me?